# Creating a cookie using radio buttons

Tags: c#, cookies, model-view-controller

***This is now solved, leaving it here for others to find***

I have tried to find the answer to the question, although I'm fairly new to this, I could have had the answer staring me in the face. So I do apologise.

I have created a MVC web app which basically saves a selection on a radio button to a cookie and then show's the selection on the next page. I think I'm close, but could you look at the code below and see why I can't get it to show the radio button text? Thanks in advance!

This is my controller;

```
public IActionResult WriteCookies(string submitOption, bool isPersistent)
    {
        if (isPersistent)
        {
            CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
            options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
            Response.Cookies.Append("setting", submitOption, options);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append("setting", submitOption);
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Turn Registered!";

        return View("Meoryou");
    }

    public IActionResult ReadCookies()
    {
        var cookieVal = Request.Cookies["setting"];
        ViewBag.submitOption = cookieVal;

        return View("MeoryouViewReturn");
    }
```

Webviews;

```
<div class="cookieCreator">
<form asp-action="WriteCookies" asp-controller="Meoryou">

    <input type="radio" value="Sam" name="submitOption"> Sam<br />
    <input type="radio" value="Chris" name="submitOption"> Chris<br />
    <input type="radio" value="Other" name="submitOption"> Other<br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="isPersistent" value="true" /> Save for 14days?<br />
    <div style="color: black;">
        <input type="submit" name="submitOption" value="Write Cookie" />
    </div><br />
</form>

<h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4>

<h4>
    <a class="btn-lg" asp-action="ReadCookies" asp-controller="Meoryou">
        See whose turn it is.<br />
    </a>
</h4>
```

Webview Return;

```
<div>
    Turn: @ViewBag.submitOption
</div>
```